# get detailLabel value from didSelectRowAtIndexPath with UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with a detail label on the right.  I have assigned a value to a variable in my Application Delegate and everything appears to be working fine.  When I click on a row I would like to get this value for my detail screen.  The value I want to get is what would be placed in the value @"Test" below.  This value currently appears as a string "Yes" or "No" in the detail on the right of each row.

didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.arrayOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

appDelegate.selectedSetting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Select value: %@ for %@, in section: %@", @"Test", [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section]];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:settings animated:YES];
}
```

cellForRowAtIndex

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *result = nil;

if ([tableView isEqual:self.myTableView]){

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    result = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (result == nil){

        result = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.arrayOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    result.textLabel.text = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *res = (NSString *)result.textLabel.text;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"XYZ"]) {

        if ([res isEqualToString:@"ABC"]) {

            result.detailTextLabel.text = appDelegate.my_important_value;                
        } 
    }

    appDelegate.selected_value = result.detailTextLabel.text;

    result.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused here, but what you want is access to a value in this controller from the detail view controller? There are several ways but for your case it would make sense to make an instance of the app delegate in the the detail view controller and read the property from it

Comment: OK, Greg, I will try that :-)